# Show that if $f$ is analytic then $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is analytic and find its derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, cauchy-riemann-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Show that $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is analytic and find its derivative.

$f$ is analytic then C-R equations hold. Suppose $f=u+iv$.

Then $g(z)=u(x,-y)+i(-v(x,-y))$. We can observe that C-R equations hold for $g$ as well since if we set $\hat{u}(x,y):=u(x,-y)$ and $\hat{v}(x,y)=-v(x,-y)$ we get
$$
\hat{u}_x=u_x=-v_y=-\hat{v}_y
\\-\hat{u}_y=u_y=v_x=-v_x
$$
But this is not enough for to show that $g$ is analytic.

Comment: easier to directly compute the derivative of $\bar f(\bar z)$

Comment: Another one: [Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function on C. Show that $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is holomorphic on C](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1004830/42969)

Comment: Why it's not enough to show that $g$ is analytic? It is enough

Comment: Because if $g$ is analytic then C-R equations hold but the other direction is not true, isn't it? @Jakobian

Comment: @J.Doe: A function is holomorphic if (and only if) $u$ and $v$ are real-differentiable and the CR equations hold. And holomorphic functions are analytic.

Comment: It's true with some weak assumptions. For example, [Looman-Menchoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem) demands continuity. Or you could try the more elementary [Goursat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Goursat's_theorem_and_its_generalizations) which demands function to be $C^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(z) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_nz^{n}$ then $g(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \overline {a}_n z^{n}$. You can differentiate the series for $g$ term by term.

$g'$ is obtained from $f'$ the same way $g$ is obatined from $f$.

Comment: Why did you not post this to one of the duplicate targets? Finding them is not that difficult, and it is sort of a civic duty here. I cannot believe that a trusted user would not think that this question has NOT been handled earlier!